# Помогите со структурой шапки

Tags: html, css

Нужно чтобы эти 3 блока встали,как на скрине,но чтобы при адаптации сайта(когда нужно будет скрывать навигацию и ставить бургер меню) чтобы логотип не пропадал. Помогите пожалуйста, никак не могу додуматься [image: Шапка]

> Шапка

```
<header class="header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header__inner">

            <div class="header__logo">
                <img src="image/logo.png" alt="">
                <span class="logo__text"><b>MoneyEx</b>Change</span>
            </div>

            <div class="nav__site">
                <a href="#" class="nav__link">Компания</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav__link">Блог</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav__link">Контакты</a>
            </div>

            <div class="nav__user">
                <a href="#" class="nav__link">Вход</a>
                <a href="#" class="user__link">Регистрация</a>
            </div>

            <button class="nav__toggle">
                <span class="nav__toggle__item">Menu</span>
            </button>
        </div> <!--/header__inner-->
</div>
</header>
```

>

Comment: Создай ещё один специально для мобилки так же на флексах и медиазапросами включай его, а этот выключай. Я бы так делал. Наверное... :)

Comment: @Данил, присылай свой код с попыткой вёрстки

Comment: @Shilgen прислал

Comment: @ДанилСтоляров  https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/abOVvJN -так ?